# How can I record a video and synchronize it with an AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avplayer

I need to record a video and show a video with an AVPlayer at the same time. The result needs to be synchronized: if the video I'm showing is a metronome, or someone clapping, the recorded video and the player should click or clap at the same time.

I play the AVPlayer using preroll and setRate, with a delegate in the camera controller.

Using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, I've tried calling setRate on the player once fileOutput(output:didStartRecordingTo) is called, but the videos end up desynchronized, with the recorded video going behind the player.

Using an AssetWriter, I've tried calling setRate on the player once captureOutput(captureOutput:sampleBuffer) is called, and the first buffer is appended, but the result is the same.

Is there any other way to do this?

EDIT: Adding some code to show what I'm doing:

Camera with AVCaptureMovieFileOutput:

```
func startRecordingVideo() {
        guard let movieFileOutput = self.movieFileOutput else {
            return
        }

        sessionQueue.async {
            if !movieFileOutput.isRecording {

                let movieFileOutputConnection = movieFileOutput.connection(with: .video)

                movieFileOutput.setOutputSettings([AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264], for: movieFileOutputConnection!)

                let outputFileName = NSUUID().uuidString
                let outputFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent((outputFileName as NSString).appendingPathExtension("mov")!)
                movieFileOutput.startRecording(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFilePath), recordingDelegate: self)
            } else {
                movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
            }
        }
    }

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didStartRecordingTo fileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection]) {
        cameraDelegate?.startedRecording()
    }
```

Implementing delegate's startRecording in the viewController:

```
private func setRateForAll() {
        let hostTime = CMClockGetTime(CMClockGetHostTimeClock())
        activePlayers.forEach {
            $0.setRate(atHostTime: hostTime)
        }
    }
```

Once the active player or players end, I call stopRecording on the camera, and show the resulting recorded video in another player, along with the player or players I've been showing.

Comment: I've upvoted the question, sending it back to "0", because I think it is a good one, but I'm going to guess the downvote was because you described the code, but you didn't provide a snippet. I know you probably feel that is unnecessary, but for this type of Apple provided framework, there are often things that get spotted.

Comment: Thank you! I've added some code, I don't know if it will be enough. There is a lot of lines regarding the configurations of session and inputs/outputs, I don't know if showing all those lines is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the recording session master clock as the hostTime for the setRate method. The desynchronization is almost imperceptible now!

In fileOutput(output:didStartRecordingTo):

```
cameraDelegate?.startedRecording(clock: CMClockGetTime(self.session.masterClock!))
```

In the view with the players:

```
private func setRateForAll(clock: CMTime) {
        activePlayers.forEach {
            $0.setRate(atHostTime: clock)
        }
}
```